# Div CSS float cutting right side of outline or box-shadow property

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm facing a weird problem when using `float-left` property to show some `divs` inside a container. The last one is cutting the right side edge for `outline` or `box-shadow` property when applied. I'm showing the problem on the pic below:

[image: float-left error last div]

if I apply the `outline` in any other `div`, it works fine (see image below). This is happening only for the last one showed.

[image]

I'm using following `class` for each container (VOL. 1, VOL. 2, VOL. 3):

```
.container_volume {
    float: left;
    width: 150px; height: 23vh;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    background: #EDFF9E;    
}
```

And this is the outline code that is applied when user select one of the divs:

```
outline: 5px solid #FF0004
```

Does anyone knows why this happens?

**EDIT 1**

To be more specific, here goes the simple `html` I'm using:

```
<div class="content_desc_volumes scrollbar-dynamic">
    <div class="container_volume" id="container_volume_1"></div>
    <div class="container_volume" id="container_volume_2"></div>
    <div class="container_volume" id="container_volume_3"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**

Here goes the `CSS` for the parent container (`content_desc_volumes`):

```
.content_desc_volumes {
    float: left; width: 100%; 
    height: 26.3vh;         
    overflow: hidden; overflow-Y: scroll;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;         
    background: url(../img/bgConf2.jpg) #fff;   
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px #000     
}
```

PS: `scrollbar-dynamic` is a class for a jQuery plugin I'm using. I've already tried to get rid of this class, but doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you get this demo to show the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kxudtz39/

Comment: Fiddle rebased with your markup and styles. Can you get it to show the problem? It doesn't for me.

Comment: Also, have you inspected the elements with your browser's dev tools to see whether the jQuery plugin is wrapping the inner elements with anything?

Comment: @isherwood Actually no. But I just discovered what happened. I changed the margin property from `margin: 10px 0 0 10px;` to `margin: 10px 5px 0 10px;` (adding 5px on the right) and it worked. But I'm still confused on why this happens only on the last div container.

Comment: Floats are finicky. Consider using `display: inline-block` instead.

Comment: @isherwood Thank you for your help and tips. I'll do it.